# Camel bean parameter binding not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm learning Apache Camel framework, trying to implement simple bean parameter binding example.

I have the following route

```
from("timer://foo?delay=2000")
    .setBody(simple("hello"))
    .log("${body}")
    .transform(simple("<foo>${body}</foo>"))
    .log("${body}")
    .bean(DocumentProcessorBean.class, "process");
```

And the following Spring bean

```
@Component("documentProcessorBean")
public static class DocumentProcessorBean {

    public Document process(@Body Document doc, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
        System.out.println(doc);
        System.out.println(headers);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

However, the parameter binding doesn't seem to work, as I'm getting Document instance without content, as is shown in the log

```
2018-04-03 18:14:39.354  INFO 7740 --- [1 - timer://foo] route1                                   : hello
2018-04-03 18:14:39.354  INFO 7740 --- [1 - timer://foo] route1                                   : <foo>hello</foo>
[#document: null]
{breadcrumbId=ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1522768469501-0-6, firedTime=Tue Apr 03 18:14:39 EEST 2018}
```

I'm also confused about the "implicit" data formats camel uses. For example, does transformation using `simple` always return a string? What is the difference of using string, marshalled format (e.g xstream) or binding class format (POJO) in the route, or does it even matter? Generally, what are the scenarios when I need to transform between these formats in the route? And most importantly, why the bean parameter binding in this particular route doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot just `System.out.println` a `Document` instance and have it show the XML content. What you see in the log is expected, it may just show `Document: null` or something, but that does not mean there is no content.

Comment: You are right, I managed to print the value of the specific node. I was sure it was empty even when inspecting the instance members with debugger, as the implementation of the Document object is somewhat obscure. And glad to see you here, I'm enjoying your book.

Comment: If you want the XML Document as just a String type then you can define that in the bean method signature.